# Change Score Model in lavaan

Tags: r, structural-equation-modeling, latent-variable, growth-model

UPDATE: I think I was over-complicating my problem and am struggling through a new approach as described here: [paired t-test as a simple latent change score model](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/219288/paired-t-test-as-a-simple-latent-change-score-model)

I am still accepting the answer below as it does appear the model is unidentified.

If folks think this is better placed on Stack Overflow, please advise. `lavaan` questions don't seem to get picked up too frequently there, so I'm starting here.

I am trying to estimate a variation of a change score model as described in the following powerpoint: http://davidakenny.net/webinars/powerpoints/SEM/Longitudinal/Change/CSA.ppt

I don't know the author and am a bit of a novice at latent variable modeling, so I am happy to receive advice on this approach in general...

The path diagram *I think* I am estimating is as follows:

[image]

**NOTE 1: I understand that a two-wave follow-up is not preferred for growth-modeling, but this is a limitation of my data.**

**NOTE 2: I only have two indicator measures instead of three as shown in the presentation. I am thus fixing all of the loadings to 1 in order to accommodate this and ensure the model is identified.**

In `laavan`, I am specifying the model as follows:

```
LCSM_Raykov <- '
B=~ Y_11 + 1*Y_12 + 1*Y_21 + 1*Y_22
C=~ Y_21 + 1*Y_22
# regressions
C ~ X
# residual correlations
B ~~ X
B ~~ C
Y_11 ~~ Y_12
Y_21 ~~ Y_22
'

LCSM_Raykov_fit <- lavaan(LCSM_Raykov, data=dat)
```

However, I am receiving the following error message.

```
#Error in lav_model_estimate(lavmodel = lavmodel, lavsamplestats = #lavsamplestats,  : 
#  lavaan ERROR: initial model-implied matrix (Sigma) is not positive #definite;
#  check your model and/or starting parameters.
#In addition: Warning message:
#In vnames(FLAT, "ov.x", warn = TRUE) :
#  lavaan WARNING: model syntax contains variance/covariance/intercept #formulas
#  involving (an) exogenous variable(s): [X];
#  Please use fixed.x=FALSE or leave them alone
```

I am curious as to whether or not this is a problem with my data (which I cannot share) or if it is a problem with my specification.

A simulated set of data which reproduces the error is provided below:

```
dat <- structure(list(Y_11 = c(420, 354, 308, 415, 373, 354, 342, 434, 
327, 395, 315, 342, 367, 330, 436, 318, 460, 424, 384, 363, 384, 
367, 400, 333, 401, 354, 364, 369, 358, 373, 361, 384, 401, 435, 
368, 433, 360, 388, 373, 383, 349, 371, 400, 315, 342, 411, 360, 
375, 424, 326, 383, 380, 320, 424, 387, 393, 401, 366, 378, 448, 
370, 392, 414, 363, 342, 358, 411, 358, 378, 358, 388, 350, 447, 
371, 385, 361, 308, 357, 367, 371, 389, 397, 415, 370, 393, 327, 
414, 352, 417, 376, 488, 361, 384, 435, 454, 309, 407, 387, 434, 
313, 476, 409, 349, 366, 308, 333, 373, 395, 407, 404, 407, 358, 
363, 337, 354, 408, 337, 460, 378, 378, 394, 354, 352, 376, 407, 
364, 381, 443, 414, 346, 401, 373, 408, 342, 352, 400, 361, 417, 
384, 426, 364, 492, 376, 404, 333, 396, 381, 302, 433, 341, 303, 
358, 404, 337, 368, 433, 338, 407, 366, 363, 377, 338, 344, 442, 
352, 373, 380, 346, 388, 357, 397, 428, 329, 358, 354, 417, 346, 
388, 381, 378, 383, 344, 424, 373, 387, 318, 428, 435, 414, 396, 
396, 371, 348, 345, 344, 414, 378, 392, 378, 366, 460, 320, 342, 
407, 337, 326, 313, 345, 396, 351, 354, 417, 431, 467, 393, 414, 
391, 369, 303, 338, 417, 414, 358, 432, 400, 456, 411, 400, 376, 
296, 360, 327, 417, 338, 321, 388, 420, 409, 396, 400, 407, 338, 
411, 397, 394, 381, 397, 357, 381, 341, 407, 315, 421, 404, 388, 
378, 435, 467, 303, 337, 360, 261, 396, 361, 363, 430, 382, 411, 
370, 357, 404, 375, 400, 400, 381, 313, 421, 412, 341, 394, 385, 
337, 354, 341, 366, 338, 406, 378, 348, 368, 337, 483, 329, 364, 
308, 369, 437, 388, 315, 460, 382, 361, 414, 420, 355, 355, 330, 
395, 373, 321, 396, 373, 395, 373, 357, 421, 370, 379, 394, 375, 
344, 358, 407, 488, 376, 366, 412, 321, 400, 443, 391, 391, 420, 
388, 387, 330, 334, 338, 387, 361, 433, 394, 414, 373, 363, 384, 
346, 326, 417, 327, 373, 403, 375, 431, 303, 371, 381, 402, 378, 
401, 477, 384, 389, 370, 423, 383, 352, 338, 381, 349, 303, 329, 
379, 417, 400, 355, 391, 408, 420), Y_12 = c(459, 364, 358, 409, 
412, 381, 375, 412, 383, 445, 386, 397, 404, 363, 436, 343, 467, 
409, 401, 395, 412, 402, 431, 376, 394, 406, 415, 406, 370, 404, 
404, 415, 431, 422, 397, 428, 375, 406, 361, 412, 404, 372, 422, 
324, 364, 430, 378, 388, 412, 392, 404, 386, 375, 409, 401, 412, 
432, 384, 426, 412, 373, 401, 404, 384, 368, 392, 432, 388, 393, 
404, 386, 364, 452, 366, 412, 404, 346, 401, 412, 340, 404, 409, 
415, 402, 397, 364, 426, 366, 437, 414, 467, 375, 395, 430, 436, 
394, 397, 436, 427, 349, 436, 412, 349, 376, 358, 367, 402, 407, 
397, 412, 400, 363, 376, 376, 412, 445, 392, 420, 388, 400, 470, 
375, 390, 404, 406, 395, 400, 415, 412, 386, 419, 394, 402, 397, 
366, 402, 400, 432, 412, 422, 409, 437, 383, 428, 370, 417, 406, 
346, 412, 378, 375, 385, 412, 375, 404, 432, 349, 420, 393, 409, 
409, 382, 399, 437, 382, 420, 393, 385, 397, 412, 392, 444, 386, 
358, 390, 436, 381, 404, 402, 331, 419, 399, 427, 414, 402, 358, 
409, 430, 392, 428, 384, 404, 401, 409, 364, 404, 395, 404, 397, 
388, 459, 372, 406, 412, 376, 366, 377, 384, 390, 380, 409, 390, 
430, 428, 417, 392, 392, 404, 345, 392, 426, 414, 390, 422, 412, 
404, 420, 400, 422, 352, 394, 350, 424, 370, 383, 400, 412, 426, 
409, 415, 414, 370, 432, 422, 406, 409, 418, 378, 404, 380, 409, 
357, 420, 415, 406, 407, 436, 483, 359, 392, 412, 323, 414, 397, 
370, 431, 401, 445, 409, 380, 402, 399, 420, 409, 401, 358, 417, 
415, 378, 422, 414, 409, 394, 388, 390, 345, 404, 418, 388, 406, 
404, 444, 386, 412, 355, 409, 397, 397, 350, 424, 401, 400, 418, 
422, 406, 406, 360, 412, 417, 404, 397, 400, 426, 407, 390, 402, 
366, 399, 409, 422, 431, 373, 412, 432, 414, 381, 419, 373, 419, 
483, 409, 409, 409, 397, 397, 401, 368, 353, 381, 388, 404, 406, 
426, 376, 372, 404, 381, 366, 426, 358, 388, 404, 401, 436, 316, 
406, 409, 384, 395, 393, 437, 422, 395, 390, 436, 400, 390, 400, 
404, 394, 375, 390, 401, 412, 424, 397, 404, 412, 395), Y_21 = c(412, 
356, 307, 379, 337, 383, 326, 396, 304, 365, 358, 321, 363, 337, 
464, 314, 375, 383, 366, 356, 387, 330, 386, 310, 386, 368, 342, 
330, 316, 400, 347, 397, 396, 394, 316, 389, 368, 360, 297, 351, 
326, 314, 310, 310, 360, 412, 347, 375, 415, 348, 319, 351, 344, 
415, 355, 415, 396, 312, 380, 417, 321, 365, 385, 377, 358, 357, 
432, 417, 375, 330, 368, 330, 433, 325, 379, 390, 298, 344, 338, 
331, 378, 371, 408, 355, 386, 310, 400, 361, 375, 379, 471, 357, 
363, 380, 433, 353, 396, 394, 442, 325, 417, 382, 312, 307, 344, 
373, 325, 380, 386, 410, 382, 312, 347, 321, 368, 387, 355, 426, 
394, 412, 384, 321, 312, 379, 402, 352, 375, 409, 409, 342, 408, 
348, 394, 307, 344, 386, 334, 422, 378, 445, 365, 478, 330, 489, 
338, 392, 286, 380, 421, 331, 380, 360, 433, 316, 316, 405, 312, 
386, 274, 364, 366, 344, 347, 471, 375, 351, 415, 326, 351, 347, 
383, 433, 365, 321, 378, 422, 330, 375, 352, 310, 384, 325, 485, 
368, 387, 336, 446, 392, 459, 402, 389, 384, 368, 340, 330, 417, 
382, 373, 382, 389, 445, 321, 381, 348, 375, 295, 284, 307, 375, 
350, 373, 403, 449, 442, 364, 400, 379, 350, 344, 325, 407, 382, 
304, 404, 337, 443, 415, 375, 387, 307, 358, 316, 437, 316, 297, 
319, 401, 408, 368, 380, 382, 316, 437, 415, 371, 385, 397, 368, 
357, 377, 427, 422, 419, 411, 368, 365, 415, 433, 320, 358, 334, 
314, 415, 338, 361, 377, 387, 412, 314, 361, 452, 341, 400, 362, 
368, 350, 489, 421, 330, 401, 392, 375, 326, 391, 325, 356, 397, 
385, 330, 331, 321, 403, 375, 366, 326, 380, 432, 350, 330, 360, 
379, 347, 380, 412, 336, 336, 347, 440, 360, 338, 364, 360, 371, 
360, 375, 422, 340, 347, 392, 384, 300, 310, 396, 489, 312, 312, 
418, 338, 348, 437, 371, 377, 438, 336, 400, 298, 286, 284, 321, 
336, 432, 413, 392, 381, 370, 384, 386, 316, 407, 331, 352, 380, 
361, 371, 331, 356, 375, 348, 368, 389, 463, 387, 390, 368, 389, 
379, 221, 342, 387, 298, 380, 337, 366, 380, 405, 344, 379, 383, 
412), Y_22 = c(431, 403, 348, 404, 393, 397, 383, 409, 342, 405, 
412, 406, 388, 356, 447, 370, 381, 390, 350, 375, 390, 359, 409, 
354, 401, 406, 378, 390, 371, 406, 369, 408, 427, 397, 355, 406, 
391, 396, 339, 365, 400, 345, 384, 369, 377, 418, 396, 394, 402, 
428, 406, 371, 415, 411, 407, 408, 422, 348, 394, 431, 359, 412, 
402, 437, 400, 386, 427, 405, 398, 357, 432, 363, 422, 353, 400, 
397, 329, 387, 375, 351, 388, 432, 436, 363, 379, 359, 403, 402, 
411, 396, 427, 361, 384, 419, 418, 384, 433, 405, 427, 365, 441, 
422, 339, 372, 379, 382, 398, 377, 409, 418, 393, 345, 370, 404, 
400, 411, 393, 400, 369, 398, 404, 388, 385, 381, 403, 386, 417, 
419, 422, 367, 442, 404, 418, 372, 396, 411, 377, 403, 408, 462, 
405, 432, 353, 466, 380, 400, 418, 415, 421, 383, 417, 394, 398, 
366, 365, 398, 342, 383, 365, 391, 428, 396, 402, 450, 384, 403, 
391, 390, 373, 417, 418, 406, 396, 343, 390, 433, 388, 400, 371, 
345, 448, 404, 432, 393, 384, 380, 398, 402, 402, 415, 391, 402, 
414, 442, 385, 402, 381, 422, 387, 391, 397, 375, 421, 393, 400, 
368, 348, 378, 385, 394, 411, 396, 456, 422, 406, 382, 421, 422, 
360, 412, 419, 391, 353, 442, 385, 464, 408, 389, 394, 324, 395, 
345, 422, 365, 367, 358, 427, 418, 385, 402, 383, 355, 415, 402, 
428, 397, 394, 412, 373, 442, 418, 429, 411, 417, 389, 405, 402, 
405, 324, 400, 422, 352, 415, 378, 407, 448, 400, 405, 497, 422, 
406, 414, 408, 412, 406, 380, 427, 455, 403, 447, 385, 403, 393, 
406, 387, 345, 390, 418, 378, 383, 407, 448, 400, 412, 314, 415, 
408, 412, 336, 379, 428, 377, 418, 394, 415, 415, 356, 419, 385, 
357, 391, 392, 394, 400, 427, 406, 383, 420, 396, 448, 401, 377, 
389, 466, 373, 389, 388, 392, 415, 441, 391, 412, 418, 393, 437, 
329, 340, 345, 339, 378, 415, 432, 425, 406, 379, 418, 391, 386, 
425, 369, 367, 411, 411, 392, 324, 360, 397, 400, 408, 440, 433, 
397, 425, 392, 437, 393, 391, 379, 402, 448, 417, 412, 422, 388, 
406, 412, 396, 402, 402), X = c(4L, 1L, 1L, 16L, 9L, 4L, 1L, 
16L, 16L, 9L, 1L, 25L, 4L, 1L, 25L, 36L, 4L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 9L, 
1L, 4L, 9L, 4L, 25L, 9L, 9L, 4L, 9L, 9L, 36L, 4L, 4L, 25L, 1L, 
4L, 1L, 9L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 1L, 9L, 9L, 4L, 1L, 1L, 4L, 16L, 4L, 
4L, 1L, 9L, 9L, 1L, 9L, 36L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 9L, 9L, 1L, 36L, 4L, 
9L, 4L, 1L, 4L, 9L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 144L, 25L, 9L, 16L, 1L, 4L, 1L, 
4L, 16L, 16L, 9L, 9L, 1L, 16L, 1L, 4L, 25L, 4L, 4L, 1L, 16L, 
4L, 1L, 25L, 36L, 100L, 4L, 16L, 9L, 49L, 1L, 16L, 25L, 9L, 4L, 
1L, 36L, 16L, 1L, 4L, 1L, 4L, 16L, 16L, 9L, 4L, 81L, 9L, 36L, 
1L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 1L, 9L, 81L, 9L, 36L, 1L, 25L, 16L, 36L, 1L, 
4L, 36L, 4L, 1L, 9L, 9L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 100L, 9L, 4L, 16L, 150L, 
9L, 9L, 16L, 4L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 64L, 36L, 49L, 16L, 25L, 1L, 196L, 
4L, 4L, 16L, 9L, 16L, 9L, 9L, 4L, 25L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 1L, 9L, 
25L, 49L, 4L, 16L, 9L, 16L, 64L, 1L, 144L, 9L, 9L, 4L, 9L, 1L, 
9L, 81L, 9L, 4L, 81L, 9L, 9L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 324L, 1L, 49L, 4L, 
25L, 25L, 4L, 16L, 9L, 4L, 9L, 9L, 4L, 1L, 64L, 64L, 4L, 1L, 
9L, 49L, 1L, 4L, 9L, 9L, 4L, 4L, 64L, 9L, 9L, 16L, 4L, 25L, 4L, 
4L, 9L, 81L, 9L, 9L, 25L, 49L, 36L, 9L, 4L, 4L, 100L, 25L, 121L, 
9L, 25L, 1L, 4L, 16L, 4L, 9L, 36L, 144L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 9L, 100L, 
1L, 4L, 1L, 4L, 81L, 1L, 9L, 64L, 4L, 1L, 9L, 144L, 4L, 16L, 
16L, 4L, 1L, 16L, 225L, 1L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 16L, 121L, 4L, 9L, 4L, 
4L, 16L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 144L, 16L, 9L, 4L, 4L, 25L, 4L, 95L, 266L, 
4L, 4L, 4L, 1L, 25L, 9L, 1L, 1L, 4L, 1L, 144L, 4L, 1L, 9L, 1L, 
49L, 1L, 4L, 25L, 49L, 4L, 25L, 4L, 36L, 1L, 1L, 49L, 144L, 16L, 
9L, 100L, 4L, 36L, 100L, 4L, 4L, 9L, 4L, 9L, 9L, 1L, 49L, 9L, 
4L, 4L, 25L, 4L, 9L, 9L, 1L, 49L, 1L, 196L, 16L, 9L, 16L, 1L, 
4L, 1L, 9L, 4L, 1L, 1L, 4L, 75L, 121L, 1L, 9L, 1L, 4L, 49L, 36L, 
4L)), .Names = c("Y_11", "Y_12", "Y_21", "Y_22", "X"), row.names = c(1L, 
3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 15L, 16L, 18L, 20L, 22L, 
23L, 24L, 25L, 26L, 27L, 28L, 31L, 32L, 33L, 34L, 36L, 38L, 39L, 
40L, 41L, 42L, 43L, 45L, 46L, 47L, 48L, 51L, 52L, 53L, 54L, 55L, 
56L, 57L, 59L, 60L, 61L, 62L, 63L, 65L, 67L, 68L, 71L, 72L, 73L, 
74L, 75L, 76L, 77L, 80L, 81L, 82L, 83L, 84L, 85L, 86L, 87L, 88L, 
89L, 90L, 91L, 92L, 93L, 94L, 95L, 96L, 97L, 98L, 99L, 100L, 
101L, 102L, 104L, 105L, 107L, 108L, 109L, 110L, 111L, 112L, 114L, 
116L, 117L, 119L, 120L, 121L, 122L, 123L, 124L, 125L, 126L, 127L, 
128L, 129L, 130L, 131L, 132L, 134L, 135L, 136L, 137L, 138L, 139L, 
140L, 141L, 142L, 143L, 144L, 145L, 147L, 148L, 149L, 150L, 151L, 
153L, 155L, 156L, 157L, 158L, 159L, 161L, 163L, 164L, 165L, 166L, 
167L, 168L, 169L, 172L, 176L, 177L, 178L, 179L, 180L, 181L, 182L, 
183L, 184L, 185L, 187L, 188L, 189L, 190L, 191L, 193L, 194L, 195L, 
196L, 197L, 198L, 199L, 200L, 201L, 203L, 204L, 205L, 206L, 207L, 
208L, 209L, 210L, 212L, 214L, 215L, 216L, 217L, 218L, 219L, 220L, 
221L, 222L, 223L, 224L, 225L, 226L, 227L, 228L, 229L, 230L, 231L, 
232L, 236L, 237L, 238L, 239L, 240L, 241L, 242L, 244L, 245L, 247L, 
248L, 249L, 250L, 251L, 252L, 253L, 254L, 255L, 256L, 257L, 258L, 
260L, 261L, 262L, 264L, 265L, 266L, 268L, 269L, 270L, 272L, 273L, 
274L, 276L, 279L, 280L, 281L, 282L, 283L, 284L, 285L, 286L, 288L, 
289L, 290L, 291L, 292L, 293L, 294L, 296L, 297L, 298L, 300L, 301L, 
303L, 304L, 305L, 306L, 307L, 308L, 309L, 310L, 311L, 312L, 313L, 
314L, 315L, 316L, 317L, 318L, 319L, 321L, 322L, 323L, 325L, 327L, 
328L, 329L, 330L, 332L, 333L, 334L, 335L, 336L, 337L, 338L, 341L, 
342L, 343L, 345L, 346L, 347L, 348L, 349L, 350L, 351L, 353L, 355L, 
356L, 358L, 359L, 361L, 362L, 363L, 364L, 365L, 366L, 369L, 370L, 
372L, 373L, 374L, 375L, 376L, 378L, 379L, 382L, 383L, 384L, 385L, 
387L, 388L, 389L, 390L, 391L, 393L, 394L, 395L, 396L, 398L, 400L, 
401L, 402L, 405L, 406L, 407L, 408L, 409L, 410L, 411L, 412L, 413L, 
414L, 415L, 416L, 417L, 418L, 419L, 420L, 421L, 422L, 423L, 424L, 
426L, 427L, 429L, 430L, 431L, 432L, 434L, 435L, 436L, 439L, 440L, 
442L, 443L, 445L, 446L, 447L, 448L, 449L, 451L, 452L, 453L, 454L, 
455L, 457L, 458L, 459L, 460L, 461L, 462L, 463L, 464L, 466L, 467L, 
468L, 469L, 470L), class = "data.frame", na.action = structure(c(2L, 
9L, 13L, 14L, 17L, 19L, 21L, 29L, 30L, 35L, 37L, 44L, 49L, 50L, 
58L, 64L, 66L, 69L, 70L, 78L, 79L, 103L, 106L, 113L, 115L, 118L, 
133L, 146L, 152L, 154L, 160L, 162L, 170L, 171L, 173L, 174L, 175L, 
186L, 192L, 202L, 211L, 213L, 233L, 234L, 235L, 243L, 246L, 259L, 
263L, 267L, 271L, 275L, 277L, 278L, 287L, 295L, 299L, 302L, 320L, 
324L, 326L, 331L, 339L, 340L, 344L, 352L, 354L, 357L, 360L, 367L, 
368L, 371L, 377L, 380L, 381L, 386L, 392L, 397L, 399L, 403L, 404L, 
425L, 428L, 433L, 437L, 438L, 441L, 444L, 450L, 456L, 465L), .Names = c("2", 
"9", "13", "14", "17", "19", "21", "29", "30", "35", "37", "44", 
"49", "50", "58", "64", "66", "69", "70", "78", "79", "103", 
"106", "113", "115", "118", "133", "146", "152", "154", "160", 
"162", "170", "171", "173", "174", "175", "186", "192", "202", 
"211", "213", "233", "234", "235", "243", "246", "259", "263", 
"267", "271", "275", "277", "278", "287", "295", "299", "302", 
"320", "324", "326", "331", "339", "340", "344", "352", "354", 
"357", "360", "367", "368", "371", "377", "380", "381", "386", 
"392", "397", "399", "403", "404", "425", "428", "433", "437", 
"438", "441", "444", "450", "456", "465"), class = "omit"))
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your model syntax and diagram don't match.

Where is Y13 and Y23 in your model?

Parameter C is fixed to one in your syntax, but not in the model. Is that deliberate?

Where is U?

If you could post a diagram of the model you think you are running, it makes it much easier to answer questions about it.

I think that this part i the source of your troubles:

```
Y11 ~~ Y12
Y21 ~~ Y22
Y11 ~~ Y22
Y21~~ Y12
```

I think it should be:

```
Y11 ~~ Y21
Y12 ~~ Y22
```

However, if you only have four measures, I don't think the model is going to be identified.

Edit:

In your original path diagram, there were (I think) more constraints that are not shown here. It's clearer if you add constraints to the diagram - that way we can see if the constraints you have match the constraints you think you have.

Anyway, you have 5 variables, which means you have 15 moments (5 variances, 10 covariances).

You might need to explicitly add residual variances to your latent variables.

```
B ~~ B
C ~~ C
```

Edit 2:

You need residual variances in your model. They are in the diagram, but not the model. Add:

```
Y_11 ~~ Y_11
Y_12 ~~ Y_12
Y_21 ~~ Y_21
Y_22 ~~ Y_22
```

That helps, but the model won't run with:

```
B ~~ X
```

in there.

I suspect this is a local identification problem, but I can't quite get my head around why. The solution is more data - either more waves, or more variables within each wave.

Comment: I apologize for the path diagram from before. I had just copied a "close" diagram to that which was shared in the presentation. I have redrawn the model I think I am trying to estimate. Do you still think it is unidentified? The presentation (from an ostensibly reputable social psychologist) appears to indicate that fixing the loadings to 1 should help with identifiability in the two indicator case.

Comment: Note too, I have also provided a simulated set of data which produces the same error if this is helpful in providing any guidance.

Comment: This has sufficiently answered my question here - it appears the model is overidentified. If you have any thoughts about my more simple approach here: http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/219288/paired-t-test-as-a-simple-latent-change-score-model, it would be much appreciated.